# i have the anti-cheat program SSDT hook addresses, but how do i restore them?

Tags: c++, debugging

i have all the SSDT hook addresses from the anti-cheat program at a game (from kernel detective). but my code doesn't seem able to change the address hex contents. please help. thanks.

Address to be hooked:

```
Address             : 0x805D2C44
Location            : ntkrnlpa.exe [PAGE]
Len                 : 5
State               : Relative Call :: call 0x8931C5B0
Current Value       : E8 67 99 D4 08 
Original Value      : E8 95 88 FE FF 
Destination Module  : 0x8931C5B0 :: -
```

Code:

```
#define NTKRNLPA01 0x805D2C44
...
MemRelace((void *)(NTKRNLPA01), (void *)"\xE8\x95\x88\xFE\xFF", 5)
```

MemReplace function:

```
bool MemReplace(VOID *lpMem, VOID *lpSrc, DWORD len)
{
  DWORD lpflOldProtect, flNewProtect = PAGE_READWRITE;

  unsigned char *pDst = (unsigned char *)lpMem, 

  *pSrc = (unsigned char *)lpSrc;

  if (VirtualProtect(lpMem,len,flNewProtect,&lpflOldProtect))
  {
      while(len-- >0) *pDst++ = *pSrc++;
      VirtualProtect(lpMem,len, lpflOldProtect,&lpflOldProtect);
      FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess(), lpMem, len);
      return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that address resides in kernel address space, you won't be able to touch it without being in kernel land yourself (ie: without a ring0 driver, this task is not possible).

Comment: @lannyboy: yes, you need to follow the same procedure rootkits do, see: http://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c-and-c/59147-writing-drivers-perform-kernel-level-ssdt-hooking.html

Comment: thanks. this is not easy :) yea i asked questions from UC, but stackoverflow guys are more helpful... they don't actually answer people much when they are not interesting to the topics

Comment: if made a driver, at the NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING pusRegistryPath) function, i add a thread to have an infinite loop to check these addresses and to unhook the E9 offsets, will this work out?

Comment: @lannyboy: not sure, I've always avoid drivers for this kinda of thing as, imo, going to such extremes generally means you have a much bigger design flaw (that is, trusting users).

Comment: what do you think if the anti-cheat program's driver (EagleNt.sys) keep assuring its offset is always correct like every 30 seconds? my driver seems only loaded once and again the next 30 seconds, the anti-cheat program's driver (EagleNt.sys) will overwrite to its behavior again...

Comment: @lannyboy: not sure if gaurd pages are available in kernel mode, it might help in trapping when it sets its callbacks

Comment: Necrolis: thanks for reminding... what do you think for this case if the driver keeps replacing the offset every 30 seconds?

Comment: @lannyboy: I prefer a reactive approach, but in this case that would be harder, but safer, however, I'd say up the resolution to like 2 secs (best is to find out how often it is replaced and replace at double the rate, though that *will* lead to problems). relying on a resolution may lead to gaps, ie: they replace 1 sec after your update, now they have 29 sec of freedom.

Comment: You can simply do that with `memcpy` or `WriteMemory` please refer to lines 4311-4318 http://pastebin.com/dzzBuiU2

Comment: memcpy won't allowed in the ring0 programming.